# Reading data from url, fread warning

Tags: r, fread

I am reading data from a URL, the page with some additional lines about data on that page. I tried read.table and read.csv to read the URL and got the data as a list. So I tried fread to read the data, and I got the data perfectly in a table. I am getting a warning, which I realize is due to the additional lines on that site. Is there a way to avoid this warning.

```
c < fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data',header = FALSE)
```

The warning I am getting is shown below.

```
 In fread("https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data",  :
      Stopped early on line 154. Expected 13 fields but found 1. Consider fill=TRUE and 
      comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<-9999>>
```

I understand adding fill = TRUE, I can remove the warning. Then the whole page gets read. Then how will filter out the last part?

Comment: You could do what the message says and use `fill=TRUE` to get rid o the warning. Then you'll need to filter those rows out at the end.

Comment: How to I filter the rows at the end?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fill = TRUE`

```
dat <- fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data',header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
```

Then, get the subset of rows with

```
dat1 <-  dat[1:154]
```

-output

```
> head(dat1)
     V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9    V10    V11    V12    V13
1: 1870   2021                                               NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
2: 1870 -0.373 -0.256  0.277  0.027 -0.400 -0.434 -0.554 -0.409 -0.622 -0.476 -0.278 -0.306
3: 1871 -0.208 -0.090 -0.112 -0.073 -0.035 -0.049 -0.347 -0.263 -0.230 -0.368 -0.094 -0.159
4: 1872  0.028  0.121  0.024 -0.009 -0.069  0.030 -0.189 -0.213 -0.227 -0.111  0.017 -0.041
5: 1873  0.127 -0.239 -0.304 -0.196 -0.331 -0.473 -0.593 -0.688 -0.588 -0.319 -0.229 -0.233
6: 1874 -0.316 -0.308 -0.486 -0.678 -0.361 -0.351 -0.242 -0.232 -0.708 -0.999 -0.480 -0.720
> dim(dat1)
[1] 154  13
```

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the answer to my question. I just needed to `complete.cases` function to remove the rows with empty cells.

```
dat < fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/gcos_wgsp/Timeseries/Data/dmi.had.long.data',
      header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
m = dat[complete.cases(dat),]
```